# SSRS Draft Font

Tags: reporting-services

Dear All,
I have EPSON Printer.I want to print the SSRS Report in Draft Fonts,Like Draft 10cpi,Draft 12 cpi,Draft 15 cpi which are available in this printer.

is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set your own fonts for your SSRS reports.

You will need the fonts installed on all machines involved - development, the web server and on the client machines where the report will be accessed from.

If you do not want to distribute the font, then you will have to export to PDF with embedded fonts and send it out.